# Tensorflow batching arguments

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Batching looks cleaner than feed_dicts, so I'm trying to understand batching in Tensorflow.

Does the below block of code create 32 identical images in the batch that it then feeds to the queue?

```
# Creates batches of 32 images and 32 labels.
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [single_image, single_label],
      batch_size=32,
      num_threads=4,
      capacity=50000,
      min_after_dequeue=10000)
```

A bit of context: I currently have a single file containing around 50K rows. I'm using `tf.train.string_input_producer` and `tf.decode_csv` to read rows from the csv, but am confused as to what to supply to `tf.train.shuffle_batch` as an argument, the individual rows or a tensor containing all the rows read from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet in your question, the tensors `single_image` and `single_label` correspond to one image and its related label. The tensors returned from [`tf.train.shuffle_batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch), `image_batch` and `label_batch` correspond to 32 probably*-different images packed together, and the 32 related labels. TensorFlow uses a [`tf.RandomShuffleQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#RandomShuffleQueue) internally to shuffle the data, and creates additional threads to evaluate `single_image` and `single_label` so that they can be added to this queue.

The `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` function has different behaviors depending on the arguments you pass. For example, if you pass `enqueue_many=True`, then the tensors in the `tensors` argument will be interpreted as batches of elements, and TensorFlow will join them on the leading dimension (so each tensor must have the same size in the 0th dimension). Using `enqueue_many=True` you could pass your entire dataset to `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`, or you can pass batches of elements (e.g. using [`tf.ReaderBase.read_up_to()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#ReaderBase.read_up_to)).

---

* I say "probably-different" because you are using a shuffling version of the batch functions, and if your data set is small compared to the `capacity` and `min_after_dequeue` arguments, it is possible that you will see multiple copies of the same example in a single batch.

Comment: Thanks for your response; I'm still confused about where `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` draws its 32 different images from. In the code snippet in the original post, I don't see where it would have access to data other than `single_image`, judging from the arguments supplied to `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`.

Comment: What happens is that TensorFlow evaluates `single_image` and `single_label` multiple times (in a separate thread, created by `tf.train.start_queue_runners()`)  and adds these to a queue that's created inside `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`. Therefore, if `single_image` and `single_label` have a different value each time you evaluate them (e.g. because they are the result of a `ReaderBase.read()` op) then you'll get different images in the result. If `single_image` always evaluates to the same value (e.g. because it's a constant), then you'll get 32 copies of the same image.